# How do I select a row in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In my display I  have two tables in master detail relation.
(When I click the mouse on the first table - the second table refreshes with its lines)

I use the mouse clicked event for that.
Sometimes I need to put the focus on the last row - programmatically.
What is the best way to put the focus in the last row and that it will trigger the event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for example

```
int rowIndex = myTable.getRowCount - 1;
myTable#changeSelection(rowIndex, 0, false, false)
```

more in JTable's API

[myTable#changeSelection(int rowIndex, int columnIndex, boolean toggle, boolean extend)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#changeSelection%28int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean%29)